# QGIS: Use layout name as variable in field calculator for referring to a specific column?

Tags: qgis, aggregate, qgis-expression, variables

I want to do some calculations based on a column which has the same name as the layout name (Graugans in this example).

To have less typing work, I thought about using the layout name as variable. But it doesn't work, the expression dialog shows:
`No feature was found on this layer to evaluate the expression.`

But when I type the name `Graugans` instead of `@layout_name`, it works...What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

This doesn't work:

```
aggregate( 'bgrbauswertung22_4f14ac5b_b4c2_4f88_a29b_16379028da2e', 'sum',  "@layout_name")
```

This works:

```
aggregate( 'bgrbauswertung22_4f14ac5b_b4c2_4f88_a29b_16379028da2e', 'sum',  "Graugans")
```

`@layout_name` gives back `Graugans`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A double quote references a field in a layer. Here it searches for a field called `@layout_name`, which is not present in the layer.

You need to use `eval()` function to evaluate the variable `@layout_name` first:

```
aggregate('mylayer','sum',eval(@layout_name))
```